# Why parent window object Update by the child window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

opener` in my child window by the parent window.

in my parent window code is

```
var a ={"test":""};
var b=a;
```

in my child window my code is

```
top.opener.b.test="set by child";
```

Now i close this child window

now when i see `a.test` it gives me `set by child`

i don't know when i update `b` why it is update in `a`

**So How can I reset `b` by `a`**

Please help me guys.

Thanks ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `b` is not actually a copy of `a`, it is a reference to `a`. 
This means that when you reference `b` you're really referencing `a`.

More info on how objects work in JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: then how can i pass copy of a in b

Comment: This question has been answered a lot, this is the most popular answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object Also different frameworks and libraries have methods of cloning an object.